# Core18 thermal warning with ssh disabled

Tags: ssh, overheating, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I'm running an appliance snap that needs to be secure so I turned off ssh using the following command.

snap set core service.ssh.disable=true

After this command and a reboot the screen flashes constantly and now I have a red thermometer warning indicating that the unit is overheating. 
If I re-enable ssh, the screen showing my ip and host key fingerprints comes back up and the warning goes away.

This seems like a bug to me, is there any way around this?
Please help.

raspberry pi 3 
Ubuntu core 18

Comment: It looks like there is a loop going on due to the missing host keys whatever else. The error reads.
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: It looks like there is a loop going on due to the missing host keys and  whatever else. Pic of the error in this link

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XL9m6nbqH4-qml5ehY0gy_l1ojpYhdFy/view?usp=sharing)